# What collection of intervals could not be a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I got these sets and for me, all of them are topologies of $R$, but I'm confused about this exercise, I think it should have sets that are not a topology. Each $\tau_i$ consists of $R$ and $\emptyset$ and every interval: 
$$a)\, (-r,\,r)\,\text{r is positive rational number}\,$$
$$b)\, [-r,\,r]\,\text{r is positive rational number }\,$$
$$c)\, (-r,\,r)\,\text{r is positive irrational number}$$
$$d)\, [-r,\,r]\,\text{r is positive irrational number}$$
$$e)\, [-r,\,r)\,\text{r is positive real number}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$$
$$f)\, (-r,\,r]\,\text{r is positive real number}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$$
$$g)\, [-r,\,r]\, \text{ and } (-r,r) \,\text{r is positive real}\,\,\,\,\,\,$$
$$h)\, [-n,\,n]\, \text{ and } (-r,r) \,\text{n is positive natural, r is positive real}$$
Every $\tau_i$ satisfies axiom $i)$, the intersection of two any intervals from above (for each case) is clearly one of the two intervals being intersected so belongs to $\tau$, the finite union is the same argument and the infinite union is $R$ so they satisfy the axioms but the exercise asks for those who are topologies, is there any of them that is not a topology?

Comment: Why do you claim that every infinite union of those intervals is the whole $\Bbb R$? That may not be the case.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering

Comment: Because if I choose a point in R, there is an interval that contains that point and if I choose a point from an interval that point belongs to R

Comment: Yes, and I claim that the interval you've just mentioned turns out not to be among the ones you are supposed to make a union of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $1=r_1<r_2<r_3<\ldots$, where $r_n$ are rational and $\lim_n r_n=\sqrt{2}$. Does 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-r_n,r_n)
$$
belong to the set in a)?

Other examples are similar.